# Disable remaining number input fields after max total of all input fields

Tags: javascript

I have an ecommerce product that I sell a box of assorted flavor bagels. The max amount of flavors per box is 12. I have a number input field for each of the 12 flavors as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot Front end inputs]

I was able to use JavaScript to limit each individual number field from exceeding 12 but I am trying to make it where the other input fields disable once the total of all fields reaches the max of 12.

The code below is what I am using to get the total of all the fields.
but at the moment It only prevents the increase of number on an individual field once it reaches 12.

I want to prevent from adding more than 12 in total from all fields combined which will complete the box of 12 bagels

```
const totalMaxQty = 12;

getAllInputs.forEach(allInputs);

function allInputs(value) {
    value.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        sumTotal();
    });
}

function sumTotal() {
    let sumValue = document.querySelectorAll('.wapf-field-input input[type=number]');
    let currentTotal = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < sumValue.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(sumValue[i].value)) {
            currentTotal += parseInt(sumValue[i].value);
        };
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < getAllInputs.length; i++) {
    getAllInputs[i].max = totalMaxQty;
}
```

Vanilla JavaScript only, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are actually returning nothing in the sumTotal(), so simply calling it inside allInputs doesn't have any effect.

```
function sumTotal() {
    let sumValue = document.querySelectorAll('.wapf-field-input input[type=number]');
    let currentTotal = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < sumValue.length; i++) {
        if (parseInt(sumValue[i].value)) {
            currentTotal += parseInt(sumValue[i].value);
        };
    }
return currentTotal

}
```

About disabling the input fields, I suggest you use event delegation.

Put all the input fields and their labels in a container and set the event listener on it. So you don't need to set an event listener on each of the input fields in a for loop.

```
const container = document.getElementById("container")



container.addEventListener("input", handleInputs )

    function handleInputs() {

         let currentTotal=sumTotal()

         if (currentTotal===12) {

            for (let i = 0; i < getAllInputs.length; i++) {
    getAllInputs[i].disabled = true;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```